# Favicon doesn't show in all pages on IE?

Tags: html, doctype, favicon

The favicon does not work on *some* pages in IE. 
But the favicon works on these pages as well in other browsers (tested in Firefox and Chrome).

Pages not showing the favicon in IE: [link - favicon error in IE](http://www.uniguru.co.in/studyabroad/profile/australia/university-western-sydney-uws/overview/72244/info.html)

Pages showing the favicon in IE: [link - favicon works](http://www.uniguru.co.in/)

Comment: A really interesting situation! If you manage to find out the reason, please write a short answer.

Comment: I'll be honest, it's IE we're talking about here. It's probably being buggy with trying to render all the HTML5 elements. I went through all your errors in the w3c validator, and nothing popped out at me that would make your image not show up. Good luck!

Comment: For me IE10 shows icons on both pages.

Answer (score 5):

You have tagged the question with the "doctype" tag. This is a clue of what might be happening...

I am confident that the issue is related to the malformed HTML (or XHTML) tags in the document which IE fails to render the favicon. I myself already had lots of "unrelated" issues due to malformed contents. I suppose, in this case, the document which fails to render the favicon is triggering a kind-of "quirks mode" in IE.

Unfortunately, there are so many issues with both documents which turns difficult to find out what exactly is the one triggering the specific IE "quirks mode" which causes the favicon problem.

The document where favicon works raises [61 errors and 3 warnings](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.uniguru.co.in/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in the W3C markup validation service.

The document where favicon does not work in IE raises [98 errors and 25 warnings](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.uniguru.co.in/studyabroad/profile/australia/university-western-sydney-uws/overview/72244/info.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in the W3C markup validation service.

So, probably it is one of these additional 37 errors and 22 warnings at the failing favicon document which makes IE too much confused and incapable of parsing the thing as a whole.

I have not dived in the errors and warnings, because they are too many. But I'm sure that if the validation passed, favicon would be appearing at both pages.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't show the favicons images of those of don't have type="image/x-icon".

I think the best thing to do is convert them to another format. 
If you are displaying the icons manually then you could download each, convert it with an image program, and upload it to your site.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then why other pages display favicon?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: Both pages use the same `<link rel="shortcut icon" .../>` element with the same URL for the icon; the image is in ICO format, stored on a different domain. It works for one page and fails on another. Doctype is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As said on [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/favicon-a-changing-role/) article:

> Internet Explorer sees only the server MIME of the ICO file, otherwise
>   it ignores the file.

Try using this:

```
<!-- For IE6+ -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you are using

```
<link href="http://images1.content-ug.com/uniguru-cont/img/ug_favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

I want to ask you to follow a couple of steps in order to troubleshot you through your problem.

1. Copy your current favicon from [this address](http://images1.content-ug.com/uniguru-cont/img/ug_favicon.ico)
2. Rename it
3. Put it on the same directory as your problematic pages
4. Link the renamed favicon from the pages that have this problem by using the format as below (put the rel attribute first):

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon"/>
   ```

Lastly if all the above doesn't resolve your problem, then just remove the type from the link (even though i really don't think this will do any change)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I already tested above the all ways. Still the problem will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this is all browser sported:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

try this inner head tag.

Comment: This is all browser saported.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things that I discovered while attempting to find answers for your problem.

1. Make sure the favicon.ico is a valid icon file.  There are bad ico files out there that either are not true icons or they are just corrupted from a bad converter program.  So Remake favicon.ico first and for most.
2. Make sure the file name is favicon.ico and located in the root directory for easy default purposes.
3. Internet Explorer will not show/display an icon if it is on your local harddrive.  It needs to be on the internet.  That is just IE not specific to other browsers.
4. Internet Explorer also don't like to display if you do not use www before your domain name.
5. You may also want to clear cache as well to make sure you aren't looking at your old temp files.

I hope this helps you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the broken object/embed tags. Remove the markup below and the favicon should start working on that page (at least it did in my tests on IE9).

```
<object ...>
<embed class="u_v" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...>
</object>
```

You should have no need for that markup anyway, since the script immediately below it will generate the appropriate embed code for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the icon's file name as '**favicon.ico**'
2. Keep the icon in **root directory**
3. No need to include like `<link rel="" .... />`. By default it will render the icon which named 'favicon.ico'.

Answer (score -1):

IE caches the favicon. Try going to Internet Options and delete the browsing history there.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding both these lines,may be this will work

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```